# How to reduce memory usage in R while looping through dataframes

Tags: r, loops, memory-management, lapply, timespace

I have two data frames and i am doing a grouping operation based on weighted scores. I used PROFVIS to profile the code and figured that looping through the dataframes to check and add group labels is a costly operation.  I understand we can use lapply, but not sure how to parse two dataframes and a new variable for this. Please help. I just need to reduce the time and space complexity of this code using apply functions.

```
rank1<-c()
occup_cats<-c()
for(i in 1:length(data_set$primary_occupation)){
  for(j in 1:length(occup_cat_prop$Category)){
    **if((as.character(data_set$primary_occupation[i])) == (as.character(occup_cat_prop$income_source[j])))**{

      rank1[i]<-occup_cat_prop$prop[j]
      occup_cats[i]<-as.character(occup_cat_prop$Category[j])

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `idxs<-match(occup_cat_prop$income_source,data_set$primary_occupation,nomatch=0);rank1<-occup_cat_prop$prop[idxs];occup_cats<-occup_cat_prop$Category[idxs]` ??

Comment: Plesse provide some sample data and simplify your code.

Comment: Hey! I did find a solution:   occup_cats=occup_cat_prop$Category
    names(occup_cats)=occup_cat_prop$income_source
    data_set$occup_cat=occup_cats[data_set$primary_occupation]